# Excel Mac - Command + select does not work

Tags: office365, office-js

In mac version of MS excel, if I select multiple cells using Command key + select and try to copy the values on clipboard (cmd+c), an alert box pops up saying - "That command cannot be used on multiple selections".

How can one select multiple cells on excel mac? Is there any API in office JS to serve the purpose? What is the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a API related question of Excel App related. The discontinuous range selection+copy doesn't seem to be supported in Mac Excel app. If you select a rectangular grid the copy action works; but if you select non uniform range the action fails. The Office JS API does't support multi-range selection/read/write at this point. Copy API is coming is in the near roadmap, but not available yet.